# PHP form post to MySQL error

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I'm creating a php-post form, containing: Who, What, Where, Contact and date_created. 
I've made a database with these rows. [image]

Here's my HTML Form code:

```
<form id="contactform" action="post.php"> 
            <p class="contact"><label for="who">Who</label></p> 
            <input id="who" name="who" placeholder="Who are you? (First & Second name)" required="" tabindex="1" type="text"> 

            <p class="contact"><label for="email">What</label></p> 
            <input id="what" name="what" placeholder="What do you want?" required="" type="text"> 

            <p class="contact"><label for="username">Where</label></p> 
            <input id="where" name="where" placeholder="Country, City, Street..." required="" tabindex="2" type="text"> 

            <p class="contact"><label for="password">Contact</label></p> 
            <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="Phone number or email"required=""> 

                <br><br>

        <input class="buttom" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Submit" type="submit">
```

And here's the php post.php code:

```
<?php
    // Grab our POSTed form values
    // Note that whatever is enclosed by $_POST[""] matches the form input elements
    $who = $_POST["who"];
    $what = $_POST["what"];
    $where = $_POST["where"];
    $contact = $_POST["contact"];

    // Connect to our DB with mysql_connect(<server>, <username>, <password>)
    $sql_connection = mysql_connect("server_name", "admin", "password");

    mysql_select_db("database_name", $sql_connection);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO content (
                who,
                what,
                where,
                contact,
                date_created
            )
            VALUES (
                '$who',
                '$what',
                '$where',
                '$contact',
                NOW()
            )";

    mysql_query($sql, $sql_connection);

    mysql_close($sql_connection);
?>
```

When I try to post something, nothing is happening. The screen is just white, the database is empty and the url is like this:

http://my-website.com/post.php?who=Firstname+Secondname&what=Some+sentences+here-and&where=America&contact=some@website.com&submit=Submit%21

Comment: You forgot to specify the method in `<form id="contactform" action="post.php">` Thus it's sending a $_GET var :p

Comment: So what should I do then?

Comment: Change it to `<form id="contactform" action="post.php" method="post">`

Comment: @downvoters I think the OP has put some efforts in asking the question, so at least don't downvote even if it's a silly question ...

Comment: Thanks, but now it directs me to post.php with a blank page, and the database is still empty... @HamZaDzCyberDeV

Comment: You're getting an empty page because you aren;t echoing anything. The DB issue, you have to debug it, try with mysql_error() for ex: `$sql_connection = mysql_connect("server_name", "admin", "password") or die("error". mysql_error());` This will echo an error if there is something wrong with your connection. Try some google-fu, and on top of this try to migrate to PDO or MYSQLI. Good coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Just as HamZa DzCyberDeV said, you didn't specify which method you're using in `<form>` tag.

For situations when you're POSTing something in your database, just as you are now - use `method="post"` and for forms when you're searching for something, use `method="get"`. 
In case of using post method, your URL will change to only my-website.com/post.php and in case of using get method, your URL will change to something like my-website.com/post.php?... (where your things which you're getting are going) - just how you got URL after submitting.

The screen is just white because post.php (where you're going after clicking on submit button) doesn't contain anything to send to output, which you can easily do with `echo`.

For instance, you can make a new html page which will be written down with echo:

```
echo '
<html
<body>
This is my website!
</body>
</html>

';
```

Also, what you could do is to use `include()` php script which has already formed HTML, or you can check out here for some other redirect methods:
http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ht/phpredirection.htm

Just remember that PHP is language which server is processing and only HTML tags (with CSS and JS) are sent to other browser to be read.

For more about POST and GET method you can read here:

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Okey, thanks! I've added method="post" to the form. I've also added or die("error". mysql_error()); to the database connection to see if there's some errors. But when I try to post, the post.php is still empty and nothing has been posted to the database...

Comment: Are you sure you made good connectiong to database? Make it like this to be sure:

// 1. Create a database connection
$sql_connection= mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$sql_connection) {
 die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysql_select_db("database_name",$sql_connection);
if (!$db_select) {
 die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

I've put this "localhost" "root" and "" for servers because I'm using XAMPP and I've made those in settings to be like that while installing it.

Comment: Ok, now I've done all that. But it's still white when posting... Wierd.

Comment: Is it saving in database? I wrote you in my post why it's white - you're not echoing anything in script. You should make redirect or include some other script which is echoing something or has some HTML content.

Comment: Nope, it's not saving in database.

Comment: Did you close your <form> tag with </form>? Because you didn't put it up in your post. And also, I think it's good practise while using these kinds of input to do it like <input name=.... /> - to put "/" before ">".

Comment: It now says I'm connected to the database. So that's not the problem. I think the problem is something in the: $sql = "INSERT INTO content (
                who,
                what,
                where,
                contact,
    date_created
            )
            VALUES (
                '$who',
                '$what',
                '$where',
    '$contact',
                NOW()
            )";

    mysql_query($sql, $sql_connection);

    mysql_close($sql_connection);

Comment: Try to get it work without date. Reset database, make table without date and move NOW() from SQL query. Maybe there is some problem in date, I really don't know what else could be cause of the problem.

Comment: Yes, it really seems right. I made many forms, just like this one and I can't see where is problem. I've always put this $_POSTs after I'm connected with database, but I don't think that it could be problem. The only problem I was thinking that it might be is the format of date.

Comment: Okey, so the error I'm getting is: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where, contact) VALUES ('fsdnkn', 'fsdjfn', 'fndsfk', 'njdsfnsdj')' at line 1

Comment: You're missing some come or some other character - at least once I got message like that.

Answer (score 2):

why don't you try this to get an error or a clue to what is going wrong, enclose your code in try and catch blocks:

```
    try {

         // your code


    } catch ( Exception $e ) {

         echo $e->getMessage();

    }
```

Comment: Okey, so the error I'm getting is: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where, contact) VALUES ('fsdnkn', 'fsdjfn', 'fndsfk', 'njdsfnsdj')' at line 1

Comment: make sue that there is a space before the word VALUES

Comment: don't indent or use newlines in your sql statement, just put it on one line. see what happens